# Vue cli 3 display info from the package.json

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

In a vue cli 3 project I want to display a version number in the webpage. The version number lies in the `package.json` file.

The only reference to this that I found [is this link in the vue forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/in-cli3-how-to-get-version-from-package-json/34876/5).

However, I can't get the proposed solution to work.

### Things I tried

1. #### Use `webpack.definePlugin` as in the linked resource:

`vue.config.js`

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: true,

  configureWebpack: config => {
    return {
      plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env': {
            VERSION: require('./package.json').version,
          }
        })
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

Then in `main.ts` I read `process.env`, but it does not contain VERSION (I tried several variants to this, like generating a PACKAGE_JSON field like in the linked page, and generating plain values like 'foo' instead of reading from `package-json`). It never worked, it is like the code is being ignored. I guess the `process.env` is being redefined later by vue webpack stuff.

The `process` log in `main.ts` contains, however, all the stuff that `process` usually contains in a vue-cli project, like the mode and the VUE_APP variables defined in `.env` files.

2. #### Try to write to `process` right on the configure webpack function,

like:

```
 configureWebpack: config => {
   process.VERSION = require('./package.json').version
 },
```

(to be honest I did not have much hope with this, but had to try).

3. #### Tried the other solution proposed in the linked page,

like:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugin('define').tap( ([options = {}]) => {
      return [{
        ...options, // these are the env variables from your .env file, if any arr defined
        VERSION: JSON.stringify(require('./package.json').version)
      }]
    })
  }
}
```

But this fail silently too.

4. #### Use the `config.plugin('define')` syntax suggested by @Oluwafemi,

like:

```
chainWebpack: (config) => {
  return config.plugin('define').tap(
    args => merge(args, [VERSION])
  )
},
```

Where `VERSION` is a local variable defined as:

```
const pkgVersion = require('./package.json').version;

const VERSION = {
  'process.env': {
    VUE_APP_VERSION: JSON.stringify(pkgVersion)
  }
}
```

But this is not working either.

---

I am re-starting the whole project everytime, so that's not the reason why the process stuff does not show up.

**My vue-cli version is 3.0.1**.

Comment: Have you tried `process.VERSION = JSON.parse(require('./package.json')).version`?

Comment: Yeah, tried that too. But VERSION does not show up in process anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### TLDR

The following snippet in the `vue.config.js` file will do the trick, and will allow you to access the version of your app as `APPLICATION_VERSION`:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: config => {
    return {
      plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'APPLICATION_VERSION': JSON.stringify(require('./package.json').version),
        })
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

### TIP:

Don't even try to add some key to `process.env` via `webpack.definePlugin`: it won't work as you probably expect.

### Why my previous efforts did not work

At the end, I solved the issue via `webpack.DefinePlugin`. The main issue I had is that the original solution I found was using `definePlugin` to write to a `process.env.PACKAGE_JSON` variable.

This suggests that `definePlugin` somehow allows to add variables to `process` or `process.env`, which is not the case. Whenever I did log `process.env` in the console, I didn't find the variables I was trying to push into `process.env` : so I though the `definePlugin` tech was not working.

Actually, what `webpack.definePlugin` does is to check for strings at compile time and change them to its value right on your code. So, if you define an `ACME_VERSION` variable via:

```
module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: true,

  configureWebpack: config => {
    return {
      plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'ACME_VERSION': 111,
        })
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

and then, in `main.js` you print `console.log(ACME_VERSION)`, you will get `111` **properly logged**.

Now, however, this is just a **string** change at compile time. If instead of `ACME_VERSION` you try to define `process.env.VUE_APP_ACME_VERSION`...

when you log `process.env` the `VUE_APP_ACME_VERSION` key won't show up in the object. **However**, a raw `console.log('process.env.VUE_APP_ACME_VERSION')` will yield `111` as expected.

So, basically, original link and the proposed solutions were correct to some degree. However, nothing was really being added to the `process` object. I was logging `proccess.env` during my initial tries, so I didn't see anything working.

Now, however, since the `process` object is not being modified, I strongly suggest anyone trying to load variables to their vue app at compile time not to use it. Is misleading at best.

Answer (score 23):

I am adding my 2 cents, as I found a **shorter way and apparently the right way (https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#packagejson-vars)**

Add this in your vue.config.file before the export, not inside:

`process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION = process.env.npm_package_version`

And voilà!

You can then use it from a component with `process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION`

Comment: This. Thanks! Super handy! Stay safe

Comment: why not just use `process.env.npm_package_version` in the component?

Comment: This variable didn't seem to be available directly in the component. You can read more here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code

Comment: Hi. Sorry what is a vue.config.file -- did you mean vite config? (I am a newbie.. maybe its a Vue3 difference?)

Comment: Yes it's same system if you are using vite, but in this question the user is using vue-cli so there is a vue.config.js file. If you use vite, process.env variables are accessible via `import.meta.env.` instead. and you don't need the `VUE_APP_` prefix I think

Answer (score 7):

You can simply import your package.json file and use its variables.

```
import { version } from "../../package.json";

console.log(version)
```

If you are using Webpack, you can inject the variable in the following way:

```
// webpack.config.js
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      VERSION: JSON.stringify(require("package.json").version)
    })
  ]

// any-module.js
console.log("Version: " + VERSION);
```

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/237

Comment: Most straight forward answer that is easiest to implement.

Answer (score 3):

When building the Vue app, [environment variables that don't begin with the `VUE_APP_` prefix are filtered out](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code). `NODE_ENV` and `BASE_URL` environment variables are the exception.

*The above information applies when the environment variables are set prior to building the Vue app and not in this situation.*

In a situation where environment variables are set during the build, it's important to look at what `Vue CLI` is doing.

The `Vue CLI` [uses `webpack.DefinePlugin`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/%40vue/cli%403.1.3/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/config/base.js#L159) to set environment variables using the object returned from the call to [`resolveClientEnv`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/%40vue/cli%403.1.3/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/util/resolveClientEnv.js).

`resolveClientEnv` returns

```
{
   'process.env': {}
}
```

This means when configuring your environment variables at build time, you need to come upon a way to merge with the existing one.
You need to perform a deep merge of both arrays, so that value for `process.env` key is an object containing keys from the resolved client environment and your keys.

`chainWebpack` key in the default export for `vue.config.js` is just about one of the ways to get this done.

The arguments passed to initialize the `DefinePlugin` can be merged with new environment variables that you like to configure using the underlying `webpack-chain` API. Here is an example:

```
// vue.config.js

const merge = require('deepmerge');
const pkgVersion = require('./package.json').version;

const VERSION = {
   'process.env': {
     VERSION: JSON.stringify(pkgVersion)
   }
}

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => 
    config
      .plugin('define')
      .tap(
          args => merge(args, [VERSION])
      )
}
```

Comment: This actually makes sense, because the webpack define plugin documentation (https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) explicitly indicates to prefer this syntax. However, it did not work :-/

Comment: Tried the `deepmerge` strategy, but it didn't work. I will try in a fresh new vue-cli 3 project, to check if some changes in my project are breaking the thing out.

Comment: Thank you, I solved the issue at the end and you answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I attempted the accepted answer, and had errors. However, in the vue docs, I was able to find an answer similar (but not quite) that of `@antoni`'s answer.

In short, just have the following in `vue.config.js`:

```
process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION = require('./package.json').version

module.exports = {
  // config
}
```

[Docs 2020-10-27](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#example-staging-mode):

> You can access env variables in your application code:
>
> `process.env.VUE_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE = require('./package.json').version`
>
> During build, `process.env.VUE_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE` will be replaced by the corresponding value. In the case of `VUE_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE=some_value`, it will be replaced by `"some_value"`.
>
> In addition to `VUE_APP_*` variables, there are also two special variables that will always be available in your app code:
>
> - `NODE_ENV` - this will be one of "development", "production" or "test" depending on the mode the app is running in.
> - `BASE_URL` - this corresponds to the publicPath option in vue.config.js and is the base path your app is deployed at.

Comment: This should be accepted answer at the moment, other solutions don't work

Answer (score 2):

Your initial attempt was fine, you were just missing the `JSON.stringify` part:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {    
  configureWebpack: config => {
    return {
      plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env': {
            VERSION: JSON.stringify(require('./package.json').version),
          }
        })
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

Edit: although the [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) recommend the `'process.env.VERSION'` way (yellow panel):

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.VERSION': JSON.stringify(require('./package.json').version),
}),
```

Comment: Thank you. As you say, `JSON.stringify` was needed for the whole thing to work: otherwise, you'll get an error when trying to print it. However, it was not the reason the `VERSION` key was not showing up in my `process.env`.

Answer (score 2):

Official solutions tend to be more reliable  [Modes and Environment Variables | Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code)

TIP

You can have computed env vars in your vue.config.js file. They still need to be prefixed with VUE_APP_. This is useful for version info

```js
process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION = require('./package.json').version

module.exports = {
  // config
}
```

Comment: I solved the problem using this solution. To anyone reading this, you may need to restart the dev server to access the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/in-cli3-how-to-get-version-from-package-json/34876/7?u=bhaskar-nair2) for this on the official VueJS forum is like so:

```js
chainWebpack: config => {
  config
    .plugin('define')
      .tap(args => {
        let v = JSON.stringify(require('./package.json').version)
        args[0]['process.env']['VERSION'] = v
        return args
      })
}
```

**Description**

Add this line to your `vue.config.js` file

```js
module.exports = {
    ...
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config
            .plugin('define')
            .tap(args => {
                let v = JSON.stringify(require('./package.json').version)
                args[0]['process.env']['VERSION'] = v
                return args
            })
    }
};
```

Then you can use this in your vue files like so:

```js
version: function () {
            return process.env.VERSION
        }
```